# Android sending SOAP object over Https via ksoap2 2.5.8

Tags: android, soap, https, ksoap2

My first time posting a question here so please do not mind my mistakes here.

I'm currently making an android application fetching and sending information from a `.asmx` web service.
Everything goes well with the `ksoap2` library and am using `HttpTransportSE` to call the web service. So now what I'm trying to do is to use the **`HttpsTransportSE`** to call the web service over Https. I got **`java.security.cert.certpathvalidatorexception trustanchor for certpath not found`** exception.

I have the server certificate in **`.pfx , .jks` and `.bks`**  format.
My questions is what do i do with it to make my **`HttpsTransportSE`** call to be success?
I've read around with articles using custom `SSLSocketFactory` but am still not sure how to implement it in my application.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion/advices

Comment: is my question not clear enough or there is just no answers for my questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your ksoap library is not having the class HttpsTransportSE. you can downlaod the ksoap library of latest version "ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies". It has in built HttpsTransportSE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I felt silly enough to have not realize there is a newer version of it. Thanks alot.